# Create new list of variable from old list of variables: new names and values (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

For each variable of a list of variables, I would like to edit the name of the variable and change its values. In particular what I have to do, for each variable is:

```
% old variable
Var = [2 3 4];  

% desired output
Var_new = [var ones(1,3)];
```

-> Var_new = [2 3 4 1 1 1]

This is the way I am doing it now, but as I have many variables, I'd like to do it in a loop, but I can't figure out how.

**Edit**: the variables in the list do not follow any pattern. There are other variables in the workspace that I do not intend to include in this operation.

Comment: How are your "old" variables named and organised? Do they follow a repeatable pattern?

Comment: No, they don't follow any pattern.

Comment: How are the variables in question (the ones you wish to modify) created?

Comment: As in the provided example.

Comment: So it's not like you are loading a .mat file or something? It sounds like you could just do a search and replace, rename those variables and then use my solution.

Comment: I could do that, but I would like to keep the original variables. I could first create the new variables so that they have a pattern and then implement your method. However, I wished there was another way. I know it can be done in other programs: just create a list of variables and then add some letters to them with a loop.

Comment: @Tecon `just create a list of variables` well, you can certainly do that. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly hacky, but assuming your variables follow a fixed pattern you could do the following:

```
var1 = [2 3 4];
var2 = [4 5 6];
all_vars = whos('var*');

for i = 1:length(all_vars)
    evalin('base',[all_vars(i).name '_new=[evalin(''base'',all_vars(i).name) ones(1,3)]'])
end

var1_new =

     2     3     4     1     1     1


var2_new =

     4     5     6     1     1     1
```

---

If you do not have a fixed pattern, then you will have to manually create a list (e.g. cell array):

```
var1 = [2 3 4];
var2 = [4 5 6];
all_vars = {'var1','var2'};

for i = 1:length(all_vars)
    evalin('base',[all_vars{i} '_new=[evalin(''base'',all_vars{i}) ones(1,3)]'])
end
```

---

By the way, I am using names *var1* and *var2* only for demonstration purposes. [This is generally considered bad practice](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval).

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to know if it is possible with a list of variables that do not follow any patter.

Comment: Yes I saw your comment after I posted my answer. Assuming that your workspace only contains the variables you wish to modify, you could use `whos` with no wildcard. Is that the case? What does your workspace look like at the time you wish to make the modification?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have many other variables that I do not want to touch.

Comment: Share in your question what the workspace looks like.

Comment: Delete the variables you don't want touched (you can always save them to a MAT file first and reload them later), and then use `whos` to get the list of variables to process with @UnbearableLightness's suggested approach.